# USB-to-Serial chips or MCU with USB support - what are the options?

Tags: ftdi

I'm looking for a cheaper alternative of the FTDI chip to add USB support to an MCU, so far I like the PL-2303HX however the problem with it is there are fake copies all over the net.
And I don't see any official distributors that allow you to buy original chips online.

Does anybody have an idea where can this chip be bought? :) Preferably from some trusted distributor, as ebay is full of the fake copies.

Or can you recommend any other lower cost alternative?

If I use an MCU with built-in USB (like [this one by Atmel](http://bg.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Atmel/AT90USB162-16AU/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvqv2n3s2xjsQTu%2f4bUyWdj9YFYcQSYNcY%3d)) is this a good choice? Do I need any windows drivers in this case?

Comment: The question as it stands now is shopping advice, you should consider rewording it. It may be put on hold otherwise.

Comment: @jippie right, I changed the title a bit.

Comment: avoid the Prolific chips like the plague; even the official ones are complete crap. Every business I've ever worked with has banned them from their labs because they end up wasting so much of the developers' time trying to get them to work.

Comment: With the FTDI chips you pay for their drivers (good quality, for nearly all platforms, updated for new OSses) in the price of the chips. Sound business model IMO. There are cheaper alternatives, like the cheap PICs with USB, but are you going to write the firmware and the drivers?

Answer (score 3):

Microchip has the [MCP2200](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/devices.aspx?dDocName=en546923), which is actually a preprogrammed USB-enabled PIC. Much cheaper than FTDI. (About half the price, IIRC)

Comment: MCP2210 also looks very interesting - it is USB HID--SPI rather than USB Serial--UART. Advantages are clear - faster, less hacky, no drivers required (can use libusb), can emulate HID devices (keyboards etc), cheaper than FTDI. Disadvantages: requires external crystal and 3.3V regulator (FTDI has these built in), USB HID code is somewhat more complicated than serial/UART.

Answer (score 0):

Those are hard to come by. An alternative might be one of these from TI: [TI USB-to-Serial chips](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/interface/usb-peripheral-products.page), specially the [TUSB3410](http://www.ti.com/product/tusb3410).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the TI prices look close to the FTDI. 
I think I'll play with an MCU with built in USB for now and see how it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just answer the MCU part: Yes, this requires the CDC drivers from Atmel. What's worse, they don't ship with Windows Update.

Also [Exar](http://www.exar.com/) produces some ICs which might fit your needs.

Comment: Only if you can deal with leadless smd packages.